# Eclipse / Code::Block doesn't run the application

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, codeblocks

I have installed MinGW correctly, but unfortunately i can't run the application i am programming. There is no message error, hence the best way is to provide you picture. ***Shall I reinstall Window?***

[application run blocks at 70% - Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lPba.png)

[The application doesn't show any Hello World ! - Code::Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50RQ2.png)

This may give you hint (hopefully):
------------- Build: Debug in SOUPER (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
Target is up to date.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
-------------- Run: Debug in SOUPER (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
Checking for existence: C:\Users\afige\workspace-C\SOUPER\bin\Debug\SOUPER.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\afige\workspace-C\SOUPER\bin\Debug\SOUPER.exe"  (in C:\Users\afige\workspace-C\SOUPER.)

Comment: Avast > Paramètres >  Des activate  "DeepScreen" .

Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be related to the antivirus program Avast. After upgrading the Avast software, the problem was fixed.
I am guessing that the scan that the antivirus program does the first time it launches a new exe was getting hung on something in the MingW created exe.